# Distincting values inside a clob

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some SQL that pulls back data from a number of places and then shows it in one row, two cells. In each of the cells is a list of the data. If I break down the SQL, Originally the data would show like this:

| Name | Colortype |
| --- | --- |
| Orange | Gold |
| Yellow | Banana [CHR(10)] Gold |

Sorry for the weird table, but basically Name column has one value per row, but Colortype can have 0 to many values. The issue in my SQL is the ColorType field is a blob list of values that has been separated by a newline CHR(10). So under Yellow Name, the colortype contains Banana separated by a newline and Gold. But you can also see that Name:Orange also has a Gold colortype.

In the end of my SQL I am taking the individual rows and rolling up so that in the end I get one row, each column containing a list of values using this..

```
SELECT distinct RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, (myTableX.uo_unicode_to_sch (colortype)), CHR (10) ).EXTRACT('//text()')  ORDER BY pct_vu).GetClobVal(),',') as risk_tx,
                RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, myTableY.uo_unicode_to_sch (name)), CHR(10)).EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY pct_vu desc).GetClobVal(),',') AS name
```

Which gives me one row, the names with it's already unique 19 values. And the colortype, with it's list of 1+x non-unique values. Like this but instead of spaces between values in the cell, they are newlines.

| Name | Colortype |
| --- | --- |
| Orange Yellow | Gold Banana Gold |

This is most of the original sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT distinct  to_char(colortype),  name
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DBMS_LOB.substr(x.name, 4000) as name ,
                        DBMS_LOB.substr(x.colortype, 4000, 1) as colortype
          FROM (SELECT distinct RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, (myTableA.uo_unicode_to_A (colortype)), CHR (10) ).EXTRACT('//text()')  ORDER BY w).GetClobVal(),',') as colortype,
                                RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, myTableA.uo_unicode_to_A (name)|| ' '  || CASE WHEN w < 0.1 THEN '< 0.1' ELSE TRIM (TO_CHAR (w, CASE WHEN w < 1 THEN '0.9' ELSE '999'END)) END
                                        || '%', CHR (10)).EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY w desc).GetClobVal(),',') AS name,
                                RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,CHR (13) , CHR (10) ).EXTRACT('//text()') ).GetClobVal(),',') AS rz
                FROM (SELECT MAX (CASE WHEN z.item_type = 'Name' THEN z.value_tx END) AS name,
                             MAX (CASE WHEN z.item_type = 'Exact %' THEN TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(z.value_tx,'^\d+')) END) AS w,                             
                             MAX (CASE WHEN z.item_type = 'Class' THEN z.value_tx END) AS colortype
                      FROM myTableA.product p
                        JOIN TABLE (myTableA.z_data.get_unique_name ('r@'|| TO_CHAR (p.prod_id)))z
                                ON z.country_cd = 'US' AND z.locale_cd = 'en' AND z.section_vu = 3
                                        AND z.item_type IN ('Name','Exact %','Class')
                      GROUP BY z.sub_section_nm))x
                      JOIN TABLE (CAST (MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=(LENGTH (x.colortype)- LENGTH (REPLACE (x.colortype,x.rz)))
                                            / LENGTH (x.rz) + 1)  AS SYS.odcinumberlist)) y
                ON 1 = 1
                )
        );
```

I cannot provide the full sql, but what I'm looking for is anyone's thoughts on how to distinct a clob field in the end? I am using 12.1 Oracle.

Comment: The best option would be to fix the data model and store the colors in a child table like a sensible relational database.  Assuming that fixing the data model is off the table, I'd probably take one of the various user-defined string aggregation functions floating around (like https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#user_defined_aggregate_function) and update it to parse the data in your `clob` column and remove the duplicates.  Have `ODCIAggregateIterate` add a row to the collection and `ODCIAggregateTerminate` do the distinct.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the user defined aggregation. The originating sql is not something I can change, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods below use `LISTAGG` so if you are going to have more than 4000 characters in your result, you may need to find an alternate method of aggregation.

Since you are on Oracle 12.1, you will need a query like this:

```sql
WITH
    colors
    AS
        (SELECT 'Orange' AS name, 'Gold' AS colortype FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Yellow', 'Banana' || CHR (10) || 'Gold' FROM DUAL),
    split_colors
    AS
        (SELECT name, COLUMN_VALUE AS color
           FROM colors  c
                CROSS JOIN
                TABLE (
                    CAST (
                        MULTISET (
                                SELECT SUBSTR (TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (c.colortype,
                                                                    '[^' || CHR (10) || ']+',
                                                                    1,
                                                                    LEVEL)),
                                               1,
                                               4000)
                                  FROM DUAL
                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                       REGEXP_COUNT (c.colortype, '[^' || CHR (10) || ']+'))
                            AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST)) c1)
SELECT (SELECT LISTAGG (name, CHR (10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name
                  FROM split_colors))    AS names,
       (SELECT LISTAGG (color, CHR (10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY color)
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT color
                  FROM split_colors))    AS colors
  FROM DUAL;
```

If you were on Oracle 19c, you could use `LISTAGG DISTINCT`

```sql
WITH
    colors
    AS
        (SELECT 'Orange' AS name, 'Gold' AS colortype FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Yellow', 'Banana' || CHR (10) || 'Gold' FROM DUAL),
    split_colors
    AS
        (SELECT name, COLUMN_VALUE AS color
           FROM colors  c
                CROSS JOIN
                TABLE (
                    CAST (
                        MULTISET (
                                SELECT SUBSTR (TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (c.colortype,
                                                                    '[^' || CHR (10) || ']+',
                                                                    1,
                                                                    LEVEL)),
                                               1,
                                               4000)
                                  FROM DUAL
                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                       REGEXP_COUNT (c.colortype, '[^' || CHR (10) || ']+'))
                            AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST)) c1)
SELECT LISTAGG (DISTINCT name, CHR (10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)       AS names,
       LISTAGG (DISTINCT color, CHR (10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY color)     AS colors
  FROM split_colors;
```

Comment: (SELECT 'Orange' AS name, 'Gold' AS colortype FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Yellow', 'Banana' || CHR (10) || 'Gold' FROM DUAL),I saw a solution like this but my question is this part would I be required to definite every value that might be in that list? All distinctly 60?

Comment: no, the `colors` common table expression is just how I mimicked your sample data. When using your data, you should be be able to remove that common table expression and place your actual table name in place in the `split_colors` common table expresssion.